# What is the time complexity for given snippet?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for i = 1 to n do
   for j = 1 to i do
       for k = 1 to j do
```

What is its time complexity in terms of 'n'?

Comment: What work have you done on this problem? For example, can you state the complexity and the exact formula for `j`? For the exact formula for `k`, which makes the complexity obvious, see [Tetrahedral number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).

Comment: Looks like n^3. Although I'm pretty bad at time complexity, so I could be wrong. Also, most of these tags are irrelevant.

Comment: I've removed the tags as suggested. @BrandonIbbotson

Comment: @ShubhamDeshmukh It was not me who downvoted your question.

Comment: Sorry... my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner-most loop will obviously run `j` times. Assuming that it contains operations worth 1 time unit, this will be:

```
T_inner(j) = j
```

The middle loop will run `i` times, i.e.

```
T_middle(i) = Sum {j from 1 to i} T_inner(j)
            = Sum {j from 1 to i} j
            = i/2 * (1 + i)
```

Finally:

```
T_outer(n) = Sum {i from 1 to n} T_middle(i)
           = Sum {i from 1 to n} (i/2 * (1 + i))
           = 1/6 * n * (1 + n) * (2 + n)
           = 1/6 n^3 + 1/2 n^2 + 1/3 n
```

And this is obviously `O(n^3)`.

Note: This only counts the operations in the inner most block. It neglects the operations necessary to perform the loop. But if you include those, you will see that the time complexity is the same.

Comment: So usually when complexity of an algorithm is talked about, do they consider the operations necessary for the loops, or is it always neglected?

Comment: The operations needed to maintain the loop will always be proportional to the number of iterations (plus the initialization operations). So, this is similar to adding a constant amount to the inner block. In the end, this does not change the complexity.